# Is it possible to use time series without seasonal and cyclical patterns to forecast the future?

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to analyse a time series(blue one) that looks like this[image]

As you see it's not seasonal I tried to draw the log of this series and it's look like it's not seasonal to ?!

I wonder what's possible to do to forecast the future
 log of ts 
[image: log of ts]

Comment: looks like two intermixed processes to me

Comment: why ? is it because the log operation ?

Comment: nono, the blue line on the top chart is going up, down, up, down, up, down. Almost like the top points are one process and the lower points are another process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question means "Do I predict variable Y using variable X (X being the time) assuming Y and X are independant". So short answer is no, you can't.

Now, your affirmation that your data is not cyclical seems like jumping to conclusions imo. You might have complex cycles and hidden dependant variables that might explain part of the variance leaving you with more cyclical residuals.

Comment: So how to find out if it's  cyclical or seasonal ?

Comment: Each time series model you would try to fit includes statistical tests to validate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try using a periodogram (there are many Python packages for it) to find important parameters, for example the frequency of your signal.

For regular sampled signals, try:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html

For irregular sampled signals on the other hand, I'd suggest:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lombscargle.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanx i will look at that